# how to use pig to strip string and extract number part of string

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a string wtr which as shown bellow

wtr
10 Good

9

11.v.Good

I am trying to extract number part from this string using pig. Here is what i tried

```
xx = FOREACH xyz_process {                                                                                                      
   wtr_split = STRSPLIT(wtr,'\\.');                                                                           
   GENERATE wtr_split;                                                                                                           
};
```

I get following warning and blank xx all the way

```
2013-12-04 17:41:10,130 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning USING_OVERLOADED_FUNCTION 1 time(s). 

2013-12-04 17:41:10,130 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_CHARARRAY 1 time(s).
```

Any idea how I would do this?

Want out put like

10

9

11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STRSPLIT will return the whole string back with splits, as tuple.  [Regex](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#regex-extract) might be better here.

Comment: I tried xx =FOREACH xyz_process GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(wtr,'(.*)\\.(.*)',1); Which works for input 11.v.good and extracts 11. But I m not able to extract number from other two cases as described in post

Comment: How about "REGEX_EXTRACT(wtr,'(\\d*)',1)"